# How can I optimize my code so that I dont duplicate it

Tags: if-statement, ada, code-duplication

I'm trying to create a procedure that puts "-" between different dates and "0" if the is single digit, but i'm having a very hard time not duplicating my code.

```
   procedure put (Date : in Date_Type) is
      
   begin
    
      Put(Date.Y, Width => 1);
      Put("-");
      if Date.M <= 9 then
         Put("0");
      end if;
      Put(Date.M, Width => 1);
      Put("-");
      if Date.D <= 9 then
         Put("0");
      end if;
      Put(Date.D, Width => 1);
      
   end put;
```

This is the best solution I came up with

Comment: Consider the advantages of a [_nested subprogram_](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/subprograms.html#nested-subprograms).

Comment: The GNAT implementation of `Ada.Calendar.Formatting.Image` offers another approach.

Comment: There's also [Text_IO.Editing](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-F-3.html) for automatically outputting leading zeroes though it is probably too complex for this scenario.

Comment: nested suprograms seems interesting, i'll give it a try and update if I manage to solve something

Answer (score 2):

An example of a nested procedure is:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   subtype Year_Num is Integer range 1_900 .. 2_040;
   subtype Month_Num is Integer range 1 .. 12;
   subtype Day_Num is Integer range 1 .. 31;

   type Date_Type is record
      Y : Year_Num;
      M : Month_Num;
      D : Day_Num;
   end record;

   procedure Put (Date : Date_Type) is
      procedure zerofill (Val : in Integer) is
      begin
         Put ("-" & (if (Val < 10) then "0" else ""));
         Put (Item => Val, Width => 0);
      end zerofill;
   begin
      Put (Item => Date.Y, Width => 0);
      zerofill (Date.M);
      zerofill (Date.D);
   end Put;
   
   A_Date : Date_Type := (2022, 12, 8);
begin
   Put (A_Date);
end Main;
```

The nested nature of this answer is because the zerofill procedure is defined within the put procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Came to this solution, I didnt duplicate my code but I somehow feel like I made it more complicated

```
   procedure Zero(item : in integer) is
      
   begin
      
     Put("-");
     if item < 10 then
        Put('0');
     end if;
     Put(Item,Width =>0);
      
   end Zero;
   
   procedure put (Date : in Date_Type) is 
      
   begin
    
      Put(Date.Y, Width => 0);    
      Zero(Date.M);    
      Zero(Date.D);
      
   end put;
```